# Proper version incrementation with multiple bug fixes in same release

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

Say I have a three PRs going into the next release. Each PR is a bug fix and all have been approved for the next release. If the current version is `2.3.1`, should the next version be `2.3.2` (count all three bugs as one patch increment) or `2.3.4` (one increment for each bug).

I have read the [semver spec](https://semver.org/), but could find no mention of this specific scenario.

Comment: _"one increment for each bug"_ That sounds odd. Version increments should be done for milestones / sprints, otherwise that won't scale well for complex systems with many developers working on it.

Comment: Why would any one release increase any value by more than one? It's not a count of changes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The company I work for has a product where the R&D department increments the tiny version for every change, but not every change gets released to QA, and not every version that gets released to QA gets released by Product Management. So, the last releases were 1.8.294, 1.8.490, 1.8.628, 1.8.7(I forgot), and the next will be something above 1.8.763 (since that's the current R&D version).

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's more of a build number than a version number, then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Actually, it's kind-of *less* than a build number, since not every change results in a build. (The firmware contains an FPGA component which takes an entire workday to build, and the firmware actually contains 4 FPGA images for 4 different application domains.) So, there are less builds than changes, but more builds than releases. However, also not every commit is a change. I think that with tight feedback cycles and rapid iteration, this will become more common, since one of the key benefits of those is to decouple the engineering release cadence from marketing release cadence.

Comment: So, you will end up with the situation that not every engineering release is published, and the question then becomes how you version those. Microsoft uses two different version numbers (Windows marketing version "7" is actually engineering version "NT 6.1" etc.), but I can see "skipping" as a reasonable strategy as well.

Comment: Are you going to make three incremental builds or just one with all three fixes?

Comment: @cdkMoose just one build for all 3 fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version numbers should identify a package (executable, library,...) that a user could have access to.  Any version numbering you share with your community is telling a user what versions exist.  Creating the intermediate version numbers in your example is misleading because there isn't actually a version 2.3.3 that a user could download and run to get that fix without the other fixes.

Internally you may want to track per build version numbers or add a fourth level to your version which is the build number to provide more clarity.  For larger systems, if you had a new version number for every modification, your version numbers would be out of control.

Comment: Not to mention what should be unleashed into public / produduction.